# Swift: removing dynamically created tableview

Tags: swift

I'm a Swift newbie and I'm struggling to destroy a dynamically created nested tableview. I have a custom UIView (B) that gets nested inside a tableViewCell (A) at runtime depending on the properties of the cell. Inside this UIView (B) I dynamically create a tableView (C) that has cells relating to a variable length array of action buttons.

So the hierarchy looks something like this:

```
- TableView (A)
   |_ Custom UIView (B)
       |_ Dynamically created 'nested' TableView (C)
```

I want to make sure the nested tableview (C) is only shown for cells where action buttons are required (the length of the busActions array >= 1).
The following is the code from the custom UIView (B). It works OK but I'm seeing random instances where the tableview (C) is displayed where it shouldn't be possible (see the setupActionTable method below):

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomComponentView2: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var busName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var loyaltyDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var testButton: TestButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapButton: TestButton!

    // set the data for the action menu
    var busActions:[[String:String]] = []

    // create the action menu view
    var actionTable:UITableView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        view.frame = bounds
    }

    func setup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomComponentView2", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

    //MARK: - Tableview Delegate & Datasource
    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        return busActions.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "actionCell")
        print("Create action cell:",indexPath.row, busActions[indexPath.row]["title"]!)
        cell.textLabel?.text = busActions[indexPath.row]["title"]!
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        // do something when the tableview is selected
    }

    func setupActionTable(busId:Int){
        // set the data for the action menu

        busActions = BusinessData().getBusinessById(busId).actions!

        print("busActions: ",busActions)
        if busActions.count >= 1 {  // we have some action buttons in the array
            print("We've got some action buttons")
            actionTable = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style:UITableViewStyle.Plain)
            actionTable!.delegate = self
            actionTable!.dataSource = self

            // table size & layout
            actionTable!.rowHeight = 30.0
            let h = busActions.count*Int(actionTable!.rowHeight)

            // config
            actionTable!.scrollEnabled = false

            view.addSubview(actionTable!)
            actionTable!.reloadData()
            actionTable!.sizeActionTableView(h)
        } else {
            print("NO ACTION BUTTONS:", busActions.count)
            if(actionTable!.isDescendantOfView(self.view)) {
                print("It's there and shouldn't be!!!")  // should never be seen
                actionTable!.removeFromSuperview()
                actionTable!.reloadData()
            }
        }
        return
    }

}

extension UIView {

    /// Adds constraints to this `UIView` instances `superview` object to make sure this always has the same size as the superview.
    /// Please note that this has no effect if its `superview` is `nil` – add this `UIView` instance as a subview before calling this.
    func sizeActionTableView(h:Int) {
        guard let superview = self.superview else {
            print("Error! `superview` was nil – call `addSubview(view: UIView)` before calling `sizeActionTableView()` to fix this.")
            return
        }

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constraintStringV = "V:[subview("+String(h)+")]-0-|"
        superview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": self]))
        superview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(constraintStringV, options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["subview": self]))
    }

}
```

Can anyone see why my code isn't removing the actionTable from the view EVERY time `busActions.count == 0`?

**More Information**

In case it's relevant, the cells in TableView (A) are nested within expanding sections & cells. So when a section header is tapped, the listings appear for that section. When a specific listing is then tapped, the cell Class is changed to one which nests this UIView (B) within it.

**Update 1: added BusinessData class**

This is the BusinessData class used to provide the Custom UIView (above) with the business/action data.

```
import Foundation

class BusinessData {
    func getBusinessById(id:Int) -> Business {

        // todo: get the businesses from the DB
        let tempArray = [
            Business(busName: "Dave's Cafe", busId: 1, website: "http://www.google.com",
                actions: [["title": "About Us", "contentId": "123456", "type": "content"],
                    ["title": "Website", "url": "http://www.davescafe.com", "type": "web"]]),
            Business(busName: "Jane's Tea Room", busId: 2, website: "http://www.bbc.co.uk",
                actions: [["title": "Jane's Favourites", "contentId": "123457", "type": "content"],
                    ["title": "Website", "url": "http://www.janestearoom.com", "type": "web"]]),
            Business(busName: "Cafe Hero", busId: 3, address: "41 Acacia Ave",
                actions: [["title": "The Hero Difference", "contentId": "123456", "type": "content"]]),
            Business(busName: "The Scout Group", busId: 18, website: "http://www.scouts.org.uk"),
            Business(busName: "Village Bowls Club", busId: 5)
        ]

        // return only the specified business (filtered by busId)
        let rtnArray = tempArray.filter{$0.busId == id}
        if rtnArray.count == 1{
            return rtnArray[0]
        } else {
            return Business(busName: "Error", busId: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2: Added snippet from TableViewController (A)**

```
 // set the type of custom cell to use
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // set the data to use
        let entry = categories[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

        // create a superview which can be used by either type of custom cell
        var cell:CustomTableCellSuper = CustomTableCellSuper()

        cell.bus = entry

        // check if a cell has been tapped or not
        if entry.selected == false {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
            cell.cellComponent.busName.text = entry.busName
        } else {
            // an expanded (selected) cell

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell2
            cell.cellComponent.busName.text = entry.busName

            // actions menu
            cell.cellComponent.setupActionTable(entry.busId)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You should rethink your logic.  Nesting table views is going to be painful to use.

Comment: This looks like it might be an index path issue. If I understand you correctly, when you remove the nested table views, some rows that contain this nested view do not get removed. Can you add a snippet of your data source where you are setting the contents of the cells?

It seems a bit of an overkill, you might want to explore using different cell views in your storyboard and loading them on demand based on each case.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño Thanks. The UIView (B) is set dynamically depending on the type of cell that's required. I'll edit the Q to include the BusinessData class.

Comment: @Gargoyle Thanks for the suggestion. This hierarchy has certainly brought it's mental challenges!

Comment: The provided code doesn't include where `setupActionTable` is called. That makes it difficult to diagnose what's going on here. A common root cause for similar issues has been failing to account for table view cell reuse correctly but there isn't enough information here to know if that's part of this problem.

Comment: @Jonah thanks for looking at this - I've added a snippet from the TableViewController (A) which I hope helps make things clearer. Getting late here now so will hit the hay and look at this with fresh eyes in the morning.

Comment: Are you refreshing the tableViewController (A) when your data changes? i.e. when your Business class actions become 0?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño & @Jonah - your hints pointed me in the direction of a working solution. In the TableViewController I've added the line `cell.cellComponent.actionTable?.removeFromSuperview()` directly before I call `cell.cellComponent.setupActionTable(entry.busId)`. This way I'm removing any actionTable that might exist - effectively reseting the UIView (B) to an untouched state. If an actionTable is required, it's created in the next line. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good stuff! happy to know my input was somehow helpful. Cheers!